# Annihilation of virtual particles

Tags: conservation-laws, coulombs-law, virtual-particles

Consider this scenario. We have two virtual particles form in a point in space. Let us consider them to be electron-positron pair. Now suppose an ELectron (not virtual) comes near the positron, nearer to the positron than the virtual electron which was the part of the virtual particles pair.
If suppose the intrinsic angular momentum of both the position and the ELectron is ½ and that of the electron is -½ (fort conservation of spin momentum of the virtual particles.

Therefore,

spin before= ½ (from ELectron)

spin during= ½+½-½

spin after= ?

If the positron and ELectron annihilate, the total spin after will be -½. According to Coulomb's law, they should attract each other and since they are opposite in charge should probably annihilate each other. But doing that would break the conservation of intrinsic angular momentum. So, to satisfy the conservation of intrinsic angular momentum do they not annihilate each other and only the virtual particles take part in the annihilation even though the Coulomb attraction between positron and ELectron is greater than positron and electron?

[image]

Comment: I think you are ascribing too many properties of real particles, to the (mysterious and far more mathematical) process behind particle interactions: related: https://profmattstrassler.com/articles-and-posts/particle-physics-basics/virtual-particles-what-are-they/

Comment: This seems to be a common lore @StudyStudy, but then one realizes that there is no such thing as an asymptotic state, all "external legs" in a physical process eventually interact with other states before reaching infinite, hence being asymptotic on-shellness HAS to be an approximation that is useful for computations, but not an intrinsic property of reality

Comment: @lurscher can you elaborate more on this to answer my question, please?

Comment: My (complete beginner) guess to one aspect of  @lurscher comment. Technically speaking, every real (as opposed to virtual) photon emitted by say, a star 100 light years away may be considered as virtual until you see the star, then  the connection between the electron in the star and the electron in your eye is made.  If you search for "on mass shell" in Wikipedia or read the following link, it might interest you: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_particle#/search

Comment: @StudyStudy i read the article you suggested. So does that mean that virtual particles created by vacuum energy do not really possess a charge? Or spin?

Comment: Hi, two good reads on this are : https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_polarization and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lamb_shift.  In the comment by lurscher above, the mention of " external legs" is a reference to the fact that when we calculate the chance of an interaction happening, we do so using calculations based on the momentum of the real particle(s), as that's all we can measure. What goes on during the interaction process itself is not something we can measure directly.  Look at: https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram

Comment: What I mean is that we can only know, by measurements and experiment, what is going on outside the intersection, the exchange of photons, for example. Where things get mixed up is that we try to put what's happening during the interaction in terms of more familiar processes outside the interaction.

Comment: @StudyStudy okay, so the process I described in the question above cannot really happen because vacuum fluctuations are, well, just fluctuations and they don't really have those properties of particles but we think of them as one to describe things in a better way. Is this correct?

Comment: "Something" occurs between the particles, and we observe and measure the results. We can't measure the actual goings on within the process, as any attempt to do so will immediately alter it. We have a theory, (QED) that we can use to calculate the probability of the event occuring, and this theory agrees with measurement extremely closely. As part of QED, we think in terms of  creation and annihilation of particles, and this works out almost fine, but it does not explain everything (Google renormalization). The math is correct, but our mental pictures are still educated guesses.

Comment: One particular book "Deep Down Things" by Bruce Schaumn is, IMO well worth reading.

Comment: Thanks @StudyStudy for your help!!